# create a matrix without using loop or nested loop operations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, nested

I want to create a matrix without using any loop, like in the following program I made in MATLAB 2011a for forming matrix `n(x,y)`.

`segment1` and `segment2` have the same dimensions (you can take any two matrices).

```
segment1 = [1 2 3;4 5 6];
segment2 = [5 2 6;9 1 2];

seg1_max = max(max(segment1));
seg2_max = max(max(segment2));

n = zeros(seg1_max, seg2_max);
i = 1; j = 1;

while i<=size(segment1, 1)        
    while j<=size(segment1, 2)    
        x = segment1(i, j);
        y = segment2(i, j);
        n(x,y) = n(x,y)+1;
        j = j+1;    
    end;
i = i+1; j = 1;
end;
```

I have also made this program using for `loop`, but i want to get matrix n(x,y) without using loop operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `accumarray` can be used for this.  Given your `segment1` and `segment2`, the following computes `m`, which will be the same as your `n`:

```
x = segment1(:);
y = segment2(:);
m = accumarray([x y], ones(size(x)));
```